# How to use Google extensions API to launch a desktop application?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I do not really find a google extensions API that launches a desktop application, but I see WebEx did it. https://meetings.webex.com/collabs/#/home Here when you host a meeting, it requires you to install the WebEx Chrome Extension. The extension then launches the desktop application. What is the magic behind it?

Is it the technology they use? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging
I see an API called "runtime.connectNative". Does it start a desktop application?

HINT: NPAPI already expired for Chrome. So NPAPI is not what WebEx used

Comment: yes its native messaging. there is also a custom url scheme that the other app could register for but im not sure if that works on desktop

Comment: When you said also do you mean Webex also use the custom url scheme like "mailto:john@company.com"? I search the web source through Chrome and I don't really see that.